# Why is spark sql returning all non null rows for like pattern '%''%' & '%' '%' even though they dont match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand why the below spark-sql code from pyspark returns all non null rows for the like pattern `'%'    '%'` or `'%''%'` even though they dont match the pattern. Spark version is 3.5.0 .

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
spark.sql('''SELECT * FROM VALUES ("a'b"), ("a[c"), (NULL) AS tab(col) where col like '%''%' ''').show()
+---+
|col|
+---+
|a'b|
|a[c|
+---+
spark.sql('''SELECT * FROM VALUES ("a'b"), ("a[c"), ("gefd"), (NULL) AS tab(col) where col like '%'    '%' ''').show()
+----+
| col|
+----+
| a'b|
| a[c|
|gefd|
+----+
```

Comment: I am running this locally on a windows laptop.

Comment: Read the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#like "The escape character is '\'. If an escape character precedes a special symbol or another escape character, the following character is matched literally. It is invalid to escape any other character.". Keep in mind that you have to escape the backslash in Python too if you aren't using a rawstring, so it would become `'%\\'%'`.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I know about that, but it dosent explain the above behaviour.

Comment: @vrivri Ah, you like to understand why this is working. I can not test it, but I can imagine that this works the same as with python: if there are two strings right next to each other, they are automatically concatenated. So `'foo' 'bar'` becomes `'foobar'` and `'%''%'` becomes `'%%'` which matches on all not NULL values.

Comment: `'%''%'` becomes `'%%'` in Python. I think in Pyspark, it is normalizing your statement using Python and yours is normalized to `'%%'`. Try `print('%' '%')` and also see `.explain(True)` instead of `show`, you should see something like `col LIKE %%`.  and `%%` means match any strings.

Comment: It was a python thing not spark, thanks for the help guys. I guess I learn something new everyday.